# Visual Studio Add Reference 4.5 dll

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm wanting to reference `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityTokenHandler` which as I understand it is available in .NET 4.5  My application in targeting 4.5, but when I go to add a reference to the `System.IdentityModel` it's 4.0

My machine has 4.7 installed on it.

How do I add a reference to a 4.5 version of `System.IdentityModel` ?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/

Comment: it looks like you have to reference that one

Comment: @DanielA.White Thanks.  I keep running into this error `'Newtonsoft.Json' already has a dependency defined for 'Microsoft.CSharp'`  I've tried updating Newtonsoft and my NuGet client.  Keep getting that error.

Comment: thats a separate question.